# SSH server accepts connection and immediately disconnects

Tags: ssh

I'm testing Bitvise SSH Server. In Setting -> Server -> Binding and UPnP, I enabled obfuscation. In Setting -> Server -> Access control, I only allow account `lv` to login. It is only me who supposed to know the password.

Now it often shows accepted connection from XXX, XXX disconnected.[image]

Does the log mean someone successfully connected to my server and know the password, but just doesn't know the keyword of obfuscation or doesn't use obfuscation?

What is wrong with the server? Is it under attack? Is `lv`'s password cracked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a difference in establishing a TCP/IP connection, completing the SSH protocol negotiation and completing the SSH authentication with success or failure.

The Internet is full of bots doing the first and failing at the second step, especially with Ssh obfuscation, which is what your logs show. That snippet doesn't show successful logins since it doesn't even show any clients achieving successful protocol negotiation. In other words: the usual internet background noise.